# How to replace number text combination in QString

Tags: qt

```
pOutputIndexFile is "G:\new1.dat"
fileNumber is "2.dat"

pOutputIndexFile->replace(QRegExp("\\[0-9]{1,1}\\.dat"),fileNumber);
```

this doesn't change my string to "G:\new2.dat". How can I do this?

Comment: well, look at the extention in your regular expression

Comment: it was the typing mistake.. i edited in the question

Comment: remove the first "\\". '[' is taken as literal.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by:

```
pOutputIndexFile->replace(QRegExp("\\d{1,10}.dat"),fileNumber);
```

\d{1,10} means match a sequence of digits that contains at least one digit but no more than ten.

So even when pOutputIndexFile is "G:\new964.dat" and fileNumber is "965.dat" the result is:

"G:\new965.dat"

Answer (score 1):

I got it fine with

```
 pOutputIndexFile->replace(QRegExp("\\d\\d?.dat"),fileNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is looking for files with the extension `idx`, not `dat`. Since it doesn't find one, nothing is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this :

```
pOutputIndexFile->replace(QRegExp("[0-9]{1}\.dat"),fileNumber);
```

- `[0-9]` : means a number
- `{1}` : means exactly one char
- `\.` : protect the `.`
- `dat` : dat